# In a noncommutative ring, is there always a pair $x,y$ such that $xy-yx=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring. Are there two element $x,y\in R$ such that $xy-yx=1_{R}$? 
I have proved it is true for $R$ being an algebra with finite dimension. 
**Sorry, I made a mistake, should be not true for $R$ being a finite dimension  algebra over a field with char $0$.**

Comment: Hi: to increase your chances of getting help, don't use bland, forgettable titles like "ring theory exercise." If you can copy the question into the title, that's often the best way to go (but it depends.) You should also include any partial work you've done so far. This makes people want to help you more, since you've already done a bit.

Comment: How did you prove it for finite dimension? As you can see it's not necessarily true... Anyway for a simple counterexample in infinite dimension, take $R\{x,y\}$ the free non-commutative $R$-algebra on two generators.

Comment: I made a mistake. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an algebra of positive finite dimension over a field of characteristic $0$, the answer is always *no*, since $1=xy-yx$ implies that the trace of multiplication by $1$, which is the dimension of your algebra, vanishes.

However, there is one very prominent example of an algebra which has the desired property, namely the *Weyl algebra* $k\langle x,\partial\rangle/([x,\partial]=1)$ which acts faithfully on the polynomial ring by multiplication and differentiation.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg There aren't many *non*commutative algebras of dimension $0$.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried with this non-commutative ring and found the answer to be no. Please check.

Consider the ring $R$ of all elements of the form $a_0+a_1i+a_2j+a_3k$ where $a_i's \in \mathbb R$. Addition is defined componentwise. Also multiplication is defined as usual by following the relation $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1; ij=jk=ki=1; kj=ji=ik=-1$. But I can not find elements in $R$ satisfying given relation.

Comment: you're right! The commutator of any two quaternions has to have constant term zero.

Comment: You're right. I think the first part of Hanno's answer is a more general version of yours. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In unital Banach algebras, the unit is not a commutator.  This is mentioned without proof on the [Wikipedia page for Banach algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra).  The proof I know relies on spectral theory: since $z\mapsto 1+z$ is entire, the spectral mapping theorem gives $\sigma(1+ba) = 1+\sigma(ba)$; but $\sigma(ab)\cup\{0\}=\sigma(ba)\cup\{0\}$, so if $ab=1+ba$ then it follows easily that $\sigma(ab)$ is unbounded, which is impossible.

Comment: Although I am not familar with Banach algebra, I'd like to thank for your help!