# How to know if there are real solutions or not?

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Consider the following system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
1 + 6(x+y) + 8xy = 0 \\ y = 6x^2 - 8 xy^2
\end{cases}
$$

If for example from the first one I solve for $x$, and then I substitute into the second one I get a fourth-degree equation, even a bit painful since it's also complete.

I checked with some program, and I found out that there are four solutions in $\mathbb{C}$, and I mean strictly complex conjugate.

My question is: is there some smart way to figure out in advance, and without programs, if there are no real solutions in this case?

Comment: Regarding a question you posted and then deleted, about a solution to $xy-yx=1$ in quaternions, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994931/in-a-noncommutative-ring-is-there-always-a-pair-x-y-such-that-xy-yx-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing OP’s comment to the answer posted by @DietrichBurde, we decided to show how to do the same without factorising. Please note that this is not an attempt to belittle the mentioned answer.

The two equation can be written as,
$$1+8xy=-6\left(x+y\right)\qquad\text{and}\tag{1}$$
$$y\left(1+8xy\right)=-6x^2.\qquad\qquad\enspace\tag{2}$$

After substituting (1) in (2), we can simplify it to get,
$$x^2+y^2+xy=0.\tag{3}$$

After adding $xy$ to both sides of (3), we have,
$$\left(x+y\right)^2=xy.\tag{4}$$

We can use (4) to replace $xy$-term in (1).
$$8\left(x+y\right)^2+6\left(x+y\right)+1=0\tag{5}$$

From (5), we obtain
$$x+y=-\dfrac{1}{4} \quad\text{or}\qquad  x+y=-\dfrac{1}{2}.$$

Using these values of $x+y$ in (4) gives,
$$xy=\dfrac{1}{16} \quad\text{or}\qquad  xy=\dfrac{1}{4}.$$

Assuming $x, y\ne 0$, we can obtain the following pair of equations.
$$x+\dfrac{1}{16x}+\dfrac{1}{4}=0\quad\longrightarrow\quad 16x^2+4x+1=0$$
$$x+\dfrac{1}{4x}+\dfrac{1}{2}=0\quad\enspace\longrightarrow\quad\enspace 4x^2+2x+1=0$$

These are the two quadratic factors Dietrich Burde has given in his answer.

Comment: Note that from $x^2+y^2+xy = 0$, you can conclude that the only real solutions are $x = y = 0$, which doesn't satisfy the original system, hence there are no real solutions. So your observation about $1+8xy$ greatly simplifies the problem, without having a bunch of tedious algebraic calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Substituting $y=-\frac{2(4x+3)}{6x+1}$ the system reduces to one equation, namely to
$$
0=64x^4 + 48x^3 + 28x^2 + 6x + 1=(16x^2 + 4x + 1)(4x^2 + 2x + 1).
$$
It is easy to see that the two quadratic equations don't have real solutions. The decomposition can be found by writing $(16x^2+ax+b)(4x^2+cx+d)$ and comparing coefficients.

Comment: Ah, I have to learn to fatorise like this... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y)$ a solution. If we assume $y=0$, we easily arrive at a contradiction so $$y\neq 0$$
We have $$\begin{cases} -8xy=1+6x+6y \\ -8xy^2=y-6x^2 \end{cases}\implies \begin{cases} -8xy^2=y+6xy+6y^2 \\ -8xy^2=y-6x^2 \end{cases}$$
So finally , $2y=x$ And I'll let you go on

Comment: Ooops : I made a mistake: we can't get $x=2y.$ Maybe we can save anyway.